# jQuery validate submits form twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery validator and jQuery 1.8.3. For some reason my form is submitted twice which causes errors. This is the code:

```
someNameSpace.myValidateFunction = function(){
    $('#myForm').validate({
        submitHandler: function(){
            mySubmitCallBackFunction();
        },
    });
    return false;
};

someNameSpace.myValidateFunction();
$(document).on('click', '#myFormSubmitButton', function(){
    $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

Any idea why the form is submitting twice? The form button is not an input submit but a `<button>` element (needed in this case).

Comment: your form html plz put here?

Comment: What does `mySubmitCallBackFunction()` do? Can you show us the code? I doubt that you need this code: `$(document).on('click', '#myFormSubmitButton', function(){
    $('#myForm').submit();
});` It appears to be the one causing your second submit. A click on the submit button should trigger the validator which should handle the submission per the submitHandler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your form is submitted twice because :

- you call `$('#myForm').submit()`
- you click on the submit button which also triggers the form event. **Note** : the , if it is in a form, will also trigger the form event on click

So I think you have to add a `return false` in your on click method to prevent the form to be submitted when you click on the submit button. Now, only `$('#myForm').submit();` will submit the form :

```
someNameSpace.myValidateFunction = function(){
    $('#myForm').validate({
        submitHandler: function(){
            mySubmitCallBackFunction();
        },
    });
    return false;
};

someNameSpace.myValidateFunction();
$(document).on('click', '#myFormSubmitButton', function(){
    $('#myForm').submit();
    return false;
});
```

I think you also don't need to add this :

```
$(document).on('click', '#myFormSubmitButton', function(){
    $('#myForm').submit();
    return false;
});
```

The validate method will be automatically called when the form is submited.

Comment: I edited my post. The submit button is NOT a submit button. It is a <button> element.

Comment: Yes but if it is a button element and it is in the form, that also trigger the submit event. You can test.

Comment: Interesting. Did not know that. But as Sandeeproops answer said, then I don't even need the whole on-click function. I removed it and it works fine now.

Comment: Yes. You don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add following code

```
$(document).on('click', '#myFormSubmitButton', function(){
  $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

submitHandler code will automatically handles form submit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:
my goal: validate many forms with the same class:

my php:

```
form class="js-validate-itemForm" method="post" action="">
...
form class="js-validate-itemForm" method="post" action="">
```

my js:

```
$('.js-validate-itemForm').each(function () {
       $(this).validate({
           submitHandler: function (form, event) { 
               doActionOnItemform(form, event);
               return false;
           }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the reason why this code would submit twice from:

```
someNameSpace.myValidateFunction = function(){
$('#myForm').validate({
    submitHandler: function(){
        mySubmitCallBackFunction();
    },
});
    return false;
};

someNameSpace.myValidateFunction();
$(document).on('click', '#myFormSubmitButton', function(){
    $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

At first, when u click button in the form, u will call `$('#myForm').submit()`, and this call event will submit one form; then form event `submitHandler:`will call ajaxsubmit to submit another form; so u will submit twice forms.

Secondly, to be honest, this code has errors -^_^- and dont understand the jQuery_validate_plugin;

If u know `$('#myForm').validate` will submit one form, u know the solution--u just delete the button call event and let `$('#myForm').validate` submit form; So that is the code：

```
someNameSpace.myValidateFunction = function(){
$('#myForm').validate({
    submitHandler: function(){
        mySubmitCallBackFunction();
    },
});
};
```

Then done!

Comment: This is basically identical to the accepted answer. If you have anything new to add please [edit] your post and add it.